# Let me really know I have a pending suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, top-bar

Suggest edits notification is hard to spot. Next to the badge number, and because of the background color, you don't really see you have a suggested edit unless you look at it directly.

I suggest we change it to s more "notificationalish" color. Blue maybe ?

> [image]

Comment: How about Orange? Red?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil It would be nice indeed. I was proposing blue because of the colors of the SE logo.

Comment: I like [light urple](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=light%20urple) the best :-D

Comment: I realize that, but since it is more of *you really need to take a look* kinda notification, a more reddish colour would be better I guess.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil It would indeed be such a contrast that we would all review them edits asap. ANyways the important thing here is "put some color there". Just not black. Let me know something lit up.

Comment: "_Every time you try and operate these weird black controls that are labeled in black on a black background, a little black light lights up in black to let you know you've done it._" -- [Zaphod Beeblebrox](http://hitchhikersguidequotes.tumblr.com/post/14488089401/its-the-wild-colour-scheme-that-freaks-me-out) in _The Restaurant At The End Of The Universe_